# Compacting products under promotion in the same container when the user's in the basket

Tags: css, arrays, sorting, bag

I have an issue understanding if it's possible or not to compact more products under promotion discount on the same container in the basket if they're competing for the same promotion.

For instance: I have one discounted promotion article in the basket that I've already added, if I add a second one that has the same promotion, is it possible to display them under a unique container, in this way they're separated from the rest of the products?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.